# Error: 'array' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c, arrays

I'm calling a function which returns a `3D array`. The problem is that if I declare the array inside the function it returns a dangling pointer as the execution of the program goes out of the scope of the variable. But when I declare the array outside the function, it gives `Error:'array' was not declared in this scope`. How should I declare the array? It returns integer type.

```
int arr[x][y][z];
int func(list of parameters)
{
  //code
  return arr;
}

int main()
{
  int arr2[x][y][z];
  arr2 = func(list of parameters);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post your code? this look like function prototype declaration error

Comment: it would be better if you show your function

Comment: "I'm calling a function which returns a 3D array". - not unless you're returning a reference (the syntax is hideous to do so, btw) or an address to something with lifetime beyond that of your function. You *can* bury your array in an object and return that, orr better still, just use a `std::vector<>` and make all of this trivial. That said, post your attempted code.

Comment: A `std::array` might be better than a vector in this case, because you can force all internal elements to be of a specific length. A vector of vectors can be 'jagged', because the internal vectors can have different lengths... this may or may not matter, but we can't tell til we see the code!

Comment: Even if I assume C++ allows assignments to array, how can you assign the return value from `func` (which is `int`) to the array `arr2` (as opposed to assignment to *an element* of this array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to return an integer value with a name `arr`, but you did not define `int arr` in the function scope.

`C` ***does not allow to return array by value***. You need to pass a pointer to an array to the function in order to let it to modify array.

Something like:

```
void func(int*** array, <list of parameters>)
{
  //code
  array[1][2][4] = 10;
}


int main()
{
  int arr2[x][y][z];
  func(arr2, <list of parameters>);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

few problems in your code:

First, `func` function should return an `int***` pointer. it is defined as returning `int` which is not the type you actually return.
Second, why retuning the global `arr` array from `func`? it simply modifies the global array.

```
int arr[x][y][z];
int func(list of parameters)
{
  //code
  return arr;
}
```

Third, why declaring arr2 to hold the result - simply reference the global array you've defined.

Fourth, defining `int arr[x][y][z];` globally is not supported - the compiler would not know how to create this buffer - you should declare it with actual size to the array (e.g., `int arr[10][10][10];`

Comment: I have declared the array with actual size only. `[x][y][z]` is for representational purpose only. Thanks for pointing out the other mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the array as a parameter in the function if you are declaring it outside the function or if you are declaring it inside the function then to deal with a dangling pointer
is for example -

```
char*func()
{
   char str[10];
   strcpy(str,"Hello!");
   return(str); 
}
//returned pointer points to str which has gone out of scope.
```

or you might be using memory that is being freed  for example

```
int *c = malloc(sizeof(int));
free(c);
*c = 3; //writing to freed location!
```